# How to add a photo-image to the comment system on my gallery?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I have a problem linking no the href of the image, but the src of the image in the comment system....

I have the following:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://eurosalute.altervista.org/search/?type=fotogallery&uri='.$urlimage_encrypt.'" data-num-posts="5" data-width="370"></div>
```

the problem is that not showed the image src, but only the link href on my gallery..
I need to show the image src in the comment system on Facebook.

For example: add a data-picture="http://eurosalute.altervista.org/search/'.$urlimage.'" or a data-src to the div, where $urlimage is the url of the image to diplay.

Please help...

Thank you,
Regards,
Rodolfo